Dafny for loop is inconsistent with forall
assert (forall i, j :: 0 <= i <= j <= end ==> monotonic(arr, i, j) ==> j - i <= endFinal - startFinal) by {
    for (int i = 0; i <= end; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j <= end; j++) {
            if (monotonic(arr, i, j)) {
                assert j - i <= endFinal - startFinal; // Ensures largest condition
            }
        }
    }
}

Even though Dafny verifies the for loop, it will not verify the forall statement. Why could this be? Are they not logically equivalent?
The logical meaning of the forall statement and the for loop should be the same. So if dafny can verify one, it should be able to verify the other.

The question is difficult to answer. You should provide the definitions of the predicate monotonic. Someone could try to guess it but since we don't even know the type of arr, (is it a seq or an array or a List?) , it's totally arbitrary. Secondly, one can not use a for loop in a proof. That's just the wrong syntax for that position. If you want to prove that assertion you need a forall expression, and/or a lemma to prove some mathematical fact about j and i. Most likely arr is dealing with some sort of array or sequence then it will require an inductive lemma to prove.
